# Trigger in sql server on different database server

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 database different server SQL Server.
Database 1 on server A
Database 2 on Server B

I want create trigger in Database 2, if data in table from database 1 added, changed or deleted trigger will be insert data in table database2.
Can i do it?

Thanks so much.

Comment: A trigger is created for a table, in the same database.

Comment: Calling a linked server in a trigger is not a good idea.  SQL Server supports other methods of *Replication*.